# "Target does not exist or is not on PATH." After 'make'-ing

Tags: c++, makefile, jgrasp

I am running `JGrasp` on Ubuntu and am having this issue every time I try to run my `make-d` program. This is the full error message:

```
 ----jGRASP exec: /home/steve/workspace/project1/BSTTest
 ----jGRASP wedge: could not execute  /home/steve/workspace/project1/BSTTest
 ----   error number 2.
 ----   
 ----   Target does not exist or is not on PATH.

 ----jGRASP: operation complete.
```

The problem is, I can see the executable `BSTTest.exe` on the left in my workspace, and I can also confirm its existence with `ls -l`.

I have spent 5+ man hours attempting to google (probably exhausted 3-4 pages of results) and solve this problem and its different forms, and would greatly appreciate any information regarding how to fix it or where the problem may be coming from.

Other information: The program makes fine, and I can compile, link and run single files perfectly fine also. The problem is I cannot run any `make'd` executables because `JGrasp` throws the "not found" error. The error should not be in my `makefile`, because I am using the `makefile` provided to me by my professor.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Executables on Linux are not usually named ".exe" and jGRASP does not expect them to be. The easiest thing is to change all "BSTTest.exe" in the makefile to "BSTTest".

Comment: Can't believe it was that easy. Thank you very much!